# body is showing undefined in pug

Tags: node.js, pug

```js
app.post('/register',  (req, res) => {

    console.log(req.body.name)

    }

);
```

```
    .container
        .row
        #registerBox.col-md-4.offset-md-4
            form.form-signup(action='/register', method='POST')
            .form-group
                label Full Name
                input.form-control(name='name', required='required', type='text')
            .form-group
                label Username
                input.form-control(name='username', required='required', type='text')
            .form-group
                label Email
                input.form-control(name='email', required='required', type='text')
            .form-group
                label Password
                input.form-control(name='password', required='required', type='password')
            .form-group
                label Confirm Password
                input.form-control(name='password2', required='required', type='password')
            button.btn.btn-lg.btn-primary.btn-block(type='submit') Register
            br
            a.text-center.new-account(href='/login') Already have an account? Sign in.
```

the second part is the pug part connected to the nodes but for some reason in the console.log it is showing undefined

Answer (score 0):

As I see the Pug code you posted, It seems like the problem is with the indentation of the submit button.

The should appear like this:

```
.container
    .row
    #registerBox.col-md-4.offset-md-4
        form.form-signup(action='/register', method='POST')
            .form-group
                label Full Name
                input.form-control(name='name', required='required', type='text')
            .form-group
                label Username
                input.form-control(name='username', required='required', type='text')
            .form-group
                label Email
                input.form-control(name='email', required='required', type='text')
            .form-group
                label Password
                input.form-control(name='password', required='required', type='password')
            .form-group
                label Confirm Password
                input.form-control(name='password2', required='required', type='password')
            button.btn.btn-lg.btn-primary.btn-block(type='submit') Register
        br
        a.text-center.new-account(href='/login') Already have an account? Sign in.
```

It happens because the button type submit has to be inside the form component. Otherwise it is not treated as the submit button of the intended form.